# Select "WHERE IN" with PostgreSQL and JSONB

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

Given table_a like this:

```
 id | name
----+------
  1 | aaaa
  2 | bbbb
  3 | cccc
```

I can obviously issue the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE name IN ('aaaa', 'bbb');
```

But given table_b like this:

```
 id |       data
----+------------------
  1 | {"name": "aaaa"}
  2 | {"name": "bbbb"}
  3 | {"name": "cccc"}
```

How do I issue a query "give me all the rows where the value of the key name is contained in this list of values?"

I know I can use the jsonb [operator @>](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) to check for each combination, but unfortunately I'd have to issue as many queries as the number of values I want to check against. Is there a way to do it **in one query**?

**UPDATE:**

I found a solution right away:

```
select * from table_b where data #>> '{name}' IN ('aaaa', 'bbb');
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE data->>'name' IN ('aaaa', 'bbbb')
```

seems like it's what you want?

Comment: Thanks, I found a similar solution in the meantime :D I'll leave the question here because I had a hard time finding it with the usual keywords on google. Apparently they have a similar query plan also.

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood: Since the answer is correct and what you needed, consider accepting it. [`json` / `jsonb` operators in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html)