# Filter JSON using IN operator in PostgreSQL DB

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

```json
{
  "List": [
    {
      "f1": "eed31964",
      "f2": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "f1": "964433d1",
      "f2": "DEF"
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON list contains 2 objects. How to filter where

`f1 IN ('eed31964','964433d1') AND f2 IN ('ABC','DEF')`.

I have tried

```
column->'List' @> '[{"f1": "eed31964"},{"f1": "964433d1"}]'
```

but this works like `AND` condition where as `IN` operator works like `OR` operator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select "WHERE IN" with PostgreSQL and JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512163/select-where-in-with-postgresql-and-jsonb)

Comment: No, I am asking about List of objects not the single object.

Comment: See if [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/6333) works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply successive `cross join`s to access the list elements, and then apply your filtering conditions:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(t1.key, t1.l) from (
   select t2.key, jsonb_agg(v.value) l 
   from tbl t cross join jsonb_each(t.js) t2 
   cross join jsonb_array_elements(t2.value) v 
   where v.value ->> 'f1' in ('eed31964','964433d1') 
       and v.value ->> 'f2' in ('ABC','DEF') 
   group by t2.key) t1
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4WxCDJB5)